# Identify Dell FX2 blade location via Redfish?

Tags: dell, ipmi, redfish

I would like to identify the location of a particular blade within a Dell FX2 chassis using Redfish. I've looked in:

- `/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1`
- `/redfish/v1/Chassis/System.Embedded.1`
- `/redfish/v1/Chassis/Chassis.Embedded.1`

But I'm not seeing anything there. Is there a way to retrieve this information from the FX2 chassis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll ask around but I believe the answer is no. The property isn't exposed in Redfish as far as I know. It's exposed via racadm with `getslotname`.

```
$ getslotname
<Slot #>  <Slot Name>                <Host Name>                <iDRAC DNS Name>
    1     SLOT-01                                               fx-idrac-640
    2     MINWINPC                   MINWINPC                   fxi2blade2-idrac
    3     SLOT-03
    4     SLOT-04
```

When you see this page on the iDRAC:

[image]

under the hood it is calling the following function:

```
function getBladeSlot(xmlDoc)
{
    var xmlNode = getXMLValue(xmlDoc, "deviceLocInfo");
    if (xmlNode != null  && typeof xmlNode == "object") {
        xmlVal = getXMLValue( xmlNode, "devBladeSlot" );
        if (xmlVal == null) xmlVal = "";
        idracBladeSlotNum = xmlVal;
        idracBladeSlotName = " " + top.localeObj["gen_slot"];
        idracBladeSlotName += (idracBladeSlotNum < 10) ? "-0" : "-";
        idracBladeSlotName += idracBladeSlotNum;
    }
}
```

which is referencing the iDRAC's internal data schema. None of this is Redfish stuff. If you wanted to go to the trouble you could definitely replicate that functionality programmatically with something like Python, but it seems much more straightforward to me to just call racadm from Python or something.

I do a lot of Redfish dev and I couldn't find anything anywhere that indicated to me that this is exposed via Redfish.

Comment: The individual nodes don't have the `getslotname` command (it's available on the CMC, but the host name and dns name columns are empty). It looks like `get system.location` includes the chassis name and slot, so that might work.

Comment: I went back and checked with the senior engineer who owns a lot of iDRAC. Confirmed - the older chassis managers do not have Redfish (the newer ones do - ex: MX7000). If there is a way to do this, neither of us saw it in the sled's endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for doing the research!